# ElasticSearch Java API set size for a FilterClient implementation

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've implemented a `FilterClient` extension for ElasticSearch that performs some (domain-specific) query rewriting depending on the incoming request. The implementation looks a bit as follows:

```
public class RewritingClient extends FilterClient {
   @Override
   protected 
       <    Request extends ActionRequest<Request>, 
            Response extends ActionResponse, 
            RequestBuilder extends ActionRequestBuilder<Request, Response, RequestBuilder>      > 
                 void doExecute(Action<Request, Response, RequestBuilder> action, Request request, ActionListener<Response> listener) {
       if (request instanceof SearchRequest) {
           SearchRequest originalRequest = (SearchRequest) request;
           SearchRequest rewrittenRequest = new SearchRequest();
           // <Perform query rewriting>
           // e.g., rewrittenRequest.indices(originalRequest.indices());
           // e.g., rewrittenRequest.source(new SearchSourceBuilder().query(<Combine original request with additional parameters>));
           super.doExecute(action, rewrittenRequest, listener);
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is that for this to work, the `rewrittenRequest` instance (i.e., another `SearchRequest` object) needs to set the parameters for the search manually (e.g., indices, types, `SearchSourceRequestBuilder`, scroll time, ...).

Is this approach the best approach to perform such a form of query rewriting with the Java API of ElasticSearch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the client would be the best place to do it, maybe an own query parser on the server side would also catch this, if a HTTP request is sent.

Wouldnt it be sufficient to replace the SearchSourceBuilder and change it appropriately. No need for serialization, but again that depends on what you want to do exactly. That might be worth talking about as well.

Comment: The place I'm performing the query rewriting is actually in a middleware between the 'actual' client and the ElasticSearch cluster. I've done some additional searching and it actually turns out that the ``SearchSourceBuilder`` is the place at which preferences such as scroll size can be set, but the client controls the expiration time of the scroll - which seems counterintuitive to me. Thanks for the insight, however!